# C# - How to use the same object more than once with different values?

Tags: c#, python, list, object

I come from a Python background when it comes to OOP and in Python you are allowed to use an object more than once and assign different values to the object.

For example, in Python I could do the following:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, colour):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.colour = colour

carList = []
car = Car("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red")
carList.append(car)
car = Car("Ford", "Focus", "Silver")
carList.append(car)
print(carList[0].make + " " + carList[0].model)
print(carList[1].make + " " + carList[1].model)
```

The output would be:

```
Ford Mondeo
Ford Focus
```

In C#, this would be different and I would appreciate it if someone would care to enlighten me as to why this is the case.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Car
    {
        private string make, model, colour;

        public Car()
        {
        }

        public void carDesc(string mke, string mdl, string clr)
        {
            make = mke;
            model = mdl;
            colour = clr;
        }

        public string getMake()
        {
            return make;
        }

        public string getModel()
        {
            return model;
        }

        public string getColour()
        {
            return colour;
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
            Car car = new Car();

            car.carDesc("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red");
            carList.Add(car);

            car.carDesc("Ford", "Focus", "Silver");
            carList.Add(car);

            Console.WriteLine(carList[0].getMake() + " " + carList[0].getModel());
            Console.WriteLine(carList[1].getMake() + " " + carList[1].getModel());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ford Focus
Ford Focus
```

Also, if it isn't possible to do what I want to do here, how would I go about working around this in order to achieve the same goal? The reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to dynamically(?) create an object instead of hard coding a set amount of objects to be filled by the end user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This in Python, creates **two distinct** `Car` objects which have nothing to do with each other, except for the type:

```py
Car("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red")
Car("Ford", "Focus", "Silver")
```

So in C#, you should also create **two distinct** `Car` objects:

```csharp
new Car("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red");
new Car("Ford", "Focus", "Silver");
```

So your `Car` constructor should probably look like this:

```csharp
public Car(string mke, string mdl, string clr)
{
    make = mke;
    model = mdl;
    colour = clr;
}
```

Comment: All the answers were correct, so thanks everyone. I chose this simply because it showed me how I could shorten my code.

Answer (score 2):

You should create ***two*** different instances of `Car` class:

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
Car car = new Car();

car.carDesc("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red");
carList.Add(car);

// You should add this: creating another instance of Car class
car = new Car();

car.carDesc("Ford", "Focus", "Silver");
carList.Add(car);

Console.WriteLine(carList[0].getMake() + " " + carList[0].getModel());
Console.WriteLine(carList[1].getMake() + " " + carList[1].getModel());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Indeed, creating two different `Car` instances is exactly what the OP's Python code does.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. When I tried to debug the code myself I tried to do `Car car = new Car();` again instead of, like you said, doing `car = new Car();`. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the same thing you are doing. if you look at your Python statement you are creating 2 new objects.
.

```
car = Car("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red")
carList.append(car)
car = Car("Ford", "Focus", "Silver")
```

The equivalent in C# is

```
car = new Car("Ford", "Mondeo", "Red");
carList.Add(car);
car = new Car("Ford", "Focus", "Silver");
carList.Add(car);
```